# Clicking custom plugin admin menu redirects to "No Update Required" on live site

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I built a custom WordPress plugin that sends Woocommerce purchase info to a CRM. The plugin works perfectly on localhost. But on the live site, whenever I click on the admin menu, I always get redirected to "No Update Required" page.

[image]

Here is my main plugin file:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Woo Crm
 * Description: Sends customer data to the CRM on purchase.
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    echo 'I am a plugin I cannot do anything when called directly.';
    exit;
}

// Config
define('PLUGIN_NAME', 'Woo Crm');
define('PLUGIN_SLUG', 'woo_crm');
define('PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));
define('PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));

// Imports
require_once(PLUGIN_PATH . 'utils/utils.php');
require_once(PLUGIN_PATH . 'views/views.php');
require_once(PLUGIN_PATH . 'services/crm/crm.php');
require_once(PLUGIN_PATH . 'views/components/settings/settings.php');

class WooCrm
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Register Styles
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'register_styles'));

        // Create Menu Page
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'plugin_setup_menu'));

        // Add Settings Fields to Menu Page
        add_action('admin_init', array('settings', 'init'));

        // Woocommerce dynamic hook from Settings API
        $hook = get_when_to_send_data_hook();
        add_action($hook, array($this, 'woo_order_create_client'));
    }

    function woo_order_create_client($order_id)
    {
        // Create client logic
    }

    function plugin_setup_menu()
    {
        $icon_url = PLUGIN_URL . "public/images/dash-icon.png";
        add_menu_page(__(PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_SLUG), __(PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_SLUG), 'manage_options', PLUGIN_SLUG, array('views', 'admin'), $icon_url);
    }

    function register_styles()
    {
        wp_register_style('woo_crm_admin', PLUGIN_URL . 'public/css/admin.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('woo_crm_admin');
    }

}

new WooCrm();
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was caused because of sloppy code design. Which lead to using too many `require`.

Changing

```
function plugin_setup_menu()
{
        $icon_url = PLUGIN_URL . "public/images/dash-icon.png";
        add_menu_page(__(PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_SLUG), __(PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_SLUG), 'manage_options', PLUGIN_SLUG, array('views', 'admin'), $icon_url);
}
```

to

```
function plugin_setup_menu()
{
        $icon_url = PLUGIN_URL . "public/images/dash-icon.png";
        add_menu_page(PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_NAME, 'manage_options', PLUGIN_SLUG, array($this,'admin_menu_view'), $icon_url);
 }
```

and adding another method

```
function admin_menu_view()
{
    include_once PLUGIN_PATH . 'views/admin.php';
}
```

fixed the issue for me.